# After filtering/sorting how to make the pagination not reset to page 1 but stay at current page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm using PagedList library for pagination and also have ordering and filtering. The problem is that after submit of order/filter request the pagination resets to page 1 but I have to keep it at current page? How can this be achieved? I also don't know if this is the right behavior but I was told to it is.

This is my controller:

```
public class ProductSearchBlockController : BlockController<ProductSearchBlock>
{
    private readonly IRepository<Products> _productsRepository;

    public ProductSearchBlockController(IRepository<Products> productsRepository)
    {
        _productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }

    public override ActionResult Index(ProductSearchBlock currentBlock)
    {
        if (Session[SessionConstants.Products] == null)
        {
            Session[SessionConstants.Products] = _productsRepository.All();
        }

        var sessionProducts = Session[SessionConstants.Products] as IEnumerable<Products>;

        var searchString = Request.QueryString.Get(RequestQueryConstants.SearchString);
        var orderBy = Request.QueryString.Get(RequestQueryConstants.OrderBy);
        var pageNumber = Request.QueryString.Get(RequestQueryConstants.PageNumber);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderBy))
        {
            orderBy = "default";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            var result = sessionProducts.Where(p => p.OrganizaitonId.Contains(searchString) ||
            p.ProductName.Contains(searchString)).ToList();

            Session[SessionConstants.ProductsResult] = result;
        }
        else
        {
            var result = sessionProducts.ToList();
            Session[SessionConstants.ProductsResult] = result;
        }

        var productsResult = Session[SessionConstants.ProductsResult] as List<Products>;

        productsResult = TableDisplayHelper.OrderedProducts(orderBy, productsResult);
        
        var viewModel = new ProductSearchBlockViewModel();

        viewModel.Products = productsResult.ToPagedList(int.Parse(pageNumber), 2);
        viewModel.PageNumber = int.Parse(pageNumber);
        viewModel.OrderBy = orderBy;
        viewModel.FilterBy = searchString;
        viewModel.Options = currentBlock.Options;

        return PartialView(viewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult GetTableData(string searchString, string orderBy, int? page)
    {
        if (searchString == null && orderBy == null)
        {
            return Redirect(PageHelper.CurrentPageUrl());
        }

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }

        int pageNumber = page ?? 1;

        var orderByQuery = UriUtil.AddQueryString(PageHelper.CurrentPageUrl(), RequestQueryConstants.OrderBy, orderBy.ToString());
        var SearchStringQuery = UriUtil.AddQueryString(orderByQuery, RequestQueryConstants.SearchString, searchString);
        var finalUrl = UriUtil.AddQueryString(SearchStringQuery, RequestQueryConstants.PageNumber, pageNumber.ToString());

        return Redirect(finalUrl);
    }
```

This is the view:

```
<div class="block esproductsearchblock col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  ">
<div class="es-product-search-block es-product-search-block-index b-spacing-default fonts-regular template-base block-wrapper">
    <div class="template-search-block wrapper-fullsize" data-is-pagination-enabled="True" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: auto;">
        <section class="product-search wrapper-940" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: auto;">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("GetTableData", "ProductSearchBlock", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <span>Order By</span>

                <select id="orderBySelect" name="orderBy" aria-hidden="true">
                    @if (Model.Options != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model.Options)
                        {
                            if (Model.OrderBy == item.Trim().ToLower())
                            {
                                <option value="@item" selected>@item</option>
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                <option value="@item">@item</option>
                            }
                        }
                    }

                </select>
                <div class="search-field bottom-aligned-m">
                    <input id="search-field-inputid" class="search-field-input" name="searchString" placeholder="Search" value="@Model.FilterBy">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                </div>
                <button class="btn">Submit Search</button>
                <a class="btn" href="/ProductSearchBlock/GetTableData">Clear Search</a>
                <div id="distribution-status-filter" data-distribution-status-filter-id="251" data-distributon-status-options="Phased out,Mature,Active"></div>
            }
        </section>

        <div class="search-results-table wrapper-940">
            <section class="results">
                <div class="products">                        
                    @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
                    {
                    <div class="product product-data">
                        <div class="title-container">
                            <p class="product-name">@product.ProductName</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                            <p class="indication">@product.OrganizaitonId</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            <h6>Price per Unit</h6>
                            <p class="small-text bold">
                                @product.Price <span class="product-price__currency-marker">€</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ProductSearchBlock", FormMethod.Get))
                        {
                            <div class="float-container">
                                <div class="float-child">
                                    <h6>Quantity</h6>
                                    <input min="1" style="width:50%" type="number" name="quantity" value="0">
                                    <input hidden type="number" name="id" value="@product.Id">
                                </div>
                                <div class="float-child">
                                    <button class="cart-btn primary-btn">Add</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>                                
                        }

                    </div>}
                </div>
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Products, page => Url.Action("GetTableData", "ProductSearchBlock",
                    new 
                    {
                        page,
                        orderBy = Model.OrderBy,
                        searchString = Model.FilterBy
                    }),
                    new PagedListRenderOptions 
                    {  
                        ContainerDivClasses = new List<string> { "pagination" }, LiElementClasses = new List<string> { "paginationSpan" } 
                    });

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "I also don't know if this is the right behavior but I was told to it is" - I would question whoever told you that. I don't see a benefit to staying on the same page 99% of the time (maybe yours is that 1% though). If the order or items is totally different, or you are adding/removing a bunch of items, staying on the same page as before essentially has no meaning.

Comment: I was told this by senior dev at my team in code review to refactor my code to work like this not to reset to page 1. In previous projects I have done it always worked like that reset to page 1 after filter and sort but this time they want like this. I found a solution posted below but maybe its not the best way.

Comment: Ok, so we have say 15 pages. We are on page 12, and we set a new filter, and now there are only 5 pages. what page are we to go to? The Last page 5? Not really sure that makes sense? You can do this, but certainly not normal behavior? So, you CAN stay on the current page, but there will be use cases where that can't happen, and thus you need to decide what to do. Do you want to then go to last page? Or go to first page if the filter results in less pages? So, a decision has to be made here. Your NEW filter can result in less pages and even less pages then the one user is currently on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @AlbertD.Kallal do you think its ok if I return to last page in that case or first page?

Comment: Your choice. I think first page is better, since then when they filter, their first question is why can't I see the first values I JUST filtered on? A new filter means a new search, and in near all cases, a new search means new information, and new information thus suggests starting at the beginning. And if you stay a few pages down, then they can miss what they were looking for. At least starting over means they will not miss what they just searched for.

Comment: Keeping the current page just doesn't make sense to me. Say you're looking through items from an online retailer. To keep things simple, say there are 100 items priced $1-$100 and 10 items per page. You go to page 3 (items $20-29) and then set a pricing filter to only show items that cost $50+. Now page 3 contains items costing $70-79. That makes no sense from a user's standpoint. Page 3 means nothing to them now and in a real-life scenario they are in a totally unexpected place in the list of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution maybe there is a better version but current one works.

Added parameter pageNumber to form and changed form to post:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetTableData", "ProductSearchBlock", new { pageNumber=Model.PageNumber}, FormMethod.Post))
```

In controller get the current page number and check if exists set page to current page

```
public ActionResult GetTableData(string searchString, string orderBy, int? page)
    {
        var currentPage = Request.QueryString.Get(RequestQueryConstants.PageNumber);

        if (searchString == null && orderBy == null)
        {
            return Redirect(PageHelper.CurrentPageUrl());
        }

        if(currentPage != null)
        {
            page = int.Parse(currentPage);
        }

        var orderByQuery = UriUtil.AddQueryString(PageHelper.CurrentPageUrl(), RequestQueryConstants.OrderBy, orderBy.ToString());
        var SearchStringQuery = UriUtil.AddQueryString(orderByQuery, RequestQueryConstants.SearchString, searchString);
        var finalUrl = UriUtil.AddQueryString(SearchStringQuery, RequestQueryConstants.PageNumber, page.ToString());

        return Redirect(finalUrl);
    }
```